# Expected running time of the binary space partition algorithm

Tags: algorithm, 3d, time-complexity, computer-science, computational-geometry

In [*Computational Geometry: Algorithms and Applications* by *Mark de Berg*](http://www.cs.uu.nl/geobook/) you can find the following [binary space partitioning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_space_partitioning) algorithm:

```
BSP(Finite set of finite non-intersecting line segments S)
{
    if (n > 1)
    {
        Use the extension of the first segment in S as the splitting line L
        Let S+ and S- be the set of fragments above and below L, respectively
        Create a tree T with left subtree = BSP(S-) and right subtree BSP(S+)
        Store all segments which overlap with L in T
    }
    else
        Create a tree T and store S in T
    return T
}
```

A *fragment* is generated, if the splitting line L cuts a segment into two halves. You may want to check out [another question of me where I give an example for this process](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1695511/why-do-at-least-half-of-all-random-orderings-generate-a-binary-space-partition-o).

[We can show](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1695511/why-do-at-least-half-of-all-random-orderings-generate-a-binary-space-partition-o) that the expected number of generated fragments by `BSP` is at most `n + 2n log(n)`, if the segments are randomly shuffled (such that each possible permutation of those segments has equal probability of appearance) and `n` denotes the number of segments.

> How can we bound the expected number of recursive calls?

In the book of *de Berg*, the authors state that the expected number of recursive calls is bounded by the expected number of generated fragments. *Why*?

---

Clearly, one splitting line `L` can produce at most `n - 1` new fragments. In the worst case, all of these new fragments are on one side of `L`. In that case each of `S+` and `S-` would contain `n - 1` elements. Thus, we would have two recursive calls with an input size of `n - 1`. This leads to a recursive running time of `T(n) = n - 1 + 2 * T(n - 1)`. [`n - 1` cause that's the count of the elements we need to test whether they are above or below `L`].

We could unroll the recursion, but I assume this will yield a very bad estimate. So, how do we need to do it? And how can we make use of the known expected number of generated fragments?

Answer (score 0):

The calls to BSP with S nonempty are in one-to-one correspondence with the generated fragments. Each call makes at most one recursive call with S empty, which makes no recursive calls, so the total number of calls is bounded by twice the number of generated fragments. It follows that this statement holds in expectation.

Comment: It's clear to me that the leaves of the call tree are either empty (i.e. `S` is empty) or contain a unique fragment. **But** I don't think that the tree is complete. Please take a look at [this example](http://imgur.com/RRMRtfP). I've extended the black segments, if they are chosen as a splitting line. They are chosen in the order 3, 6, 4, 5, 2. The corresponding call graph looks like [this](http://imgur.com/jBRjdrM). After the ":" I've written down the segments passed in the invocation. 1+ and 1- stands for the fragment above and below the splitting line induced by 3.

Comment: As you can see, the tree is not complete. Some leaves are at depth 2, others at depth 3.

Comment: @0xbadf00d I meant complete in the sense of exactly 0 or 2 children. The calls with S empty are a minor problem; see my edit.

Comment: Each call with `S` nonempty makes two recursive calls, but I don't see why the total number of recursive calls should be twice the number of generated fragments. I think one needs some argument which shows that the algorithm "makes progress". As I've written in the question, we only know that the input size of each of the recursive calls is at most `n - 1`. Could you please explain in detail why you think that the number of recursive calls should be twice the number of generated fragments?

Comment: @0xbadf00d You need to take `s1` out of the recursive calls or else you *won't* make progress.

Comment: That's already the case. `L` is the extension of the first element of `S` (formally called `s1`) and `S+` and `S-` are the segments above and below  `L`, respectively. **But** `s1` is neither above nor belov `L`; it's **on** `L`. Thus, it's already out of the recursive calls. But the question in my last comment remains.

Comment: @0xbadf00d The shape of the call tree is exactly the shape of the generated tree, except for the calls where S is empty. (I'm ignoring the case of collinear segments here.) Do you have a counterexample?

Comment: But you haven't proven or given an argument for the number of nodes of the call tree.

Comment: @0xbadf00d The nodes in the call tree with S nonempty are in one-to-one correspondence with the output tree nodes, which are in one-to-one correspondence with the generated fragments, so everything has the same count. There's a hack to handle the S empty calls.

Comment: You've said before that the number of recursive calls is at most "**twice** the number of generated fragments". So, how can there be a one-to-one correspondence? Isn't the main point that in each call with `S` nonempty, one segment (or call it fragment) is chosen and this fragment is guaranteed to be out of the next recursive calls. So, with each call we "cut out" at least one fragment. Since there are at most `n + 2n log n` fragments, the number of recursive calls is bounded by `n + 2n log n`. Do you agree?

Comment: @0xbadf00d The twice is because each call with S nonempty makes at most one call with S empty.

Answer (score 0):

"How can we bound the expected number of recursive calls?": you can't. The algorithm description explains that this expected number is bounded by the expected number of fragments, on which you have no direct control.

When the segments are sufficiently random, this number is O(N Log(N)), which is fine. But for other distributions, it could be higher or even lower.

In addition, you are also concerned by the worst case, for which the complexity might be catastrophic (like O(N²)).

To circumvent that, you should probably develop heuristics to perform the choice of the line L in such a way that the splits are balanced and do not generate too many fragments. But you can't fully avoid the worst case, just make it highly unlikely.

This situation reminds of quicksort, that has O(N Log(N)) expected behavior, but O(N²) worst case. The latter is tamed by using the "median of three" heuristic to choose the pivot.

Answer (score 0):

We show that each time the body of the algorithm is entered, one fragment is consumed:

- We can ignore the case where `S` is empty, cause this could be “hacked” in the algorithm such that a recursive invocation would be avoided
- If S contains a single element, this element is consumed (and no further recursive invocations occur)
- If S contains more than one element, at least the first element of `S` is consumed, cause it’s chosen as the splitting line `l` (and no further recursive invocations occur); in fact all elements of `S` which overlap with `l` are consumed (but again, that’s irrelevant here, cause we’re interested in a worst case bound)

Thus, the number of recursive invocations is bounded by the number of generated fragments. Since the expected number of generated fragments is `O(n ln n)`, the expected number of recursive invocations is `O(n ln n)`, too.